# No kotlin.js file output by kotlinc-js

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

Currently trying to get a Kotlin "Hello, World" to compile to JS via the command line.  I've followed the tutorial:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-command-line/command-line-library-js.html

I'm seeing the Javascript files being generated, but I'm missing the `kotlin.js` file that I would expect to see per:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/kotlin-to-javascript/kotlin-to-javascript.html

The first few lines of the generated JS files read:
`if (typeof kotlin === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error("Error loading module 'sample-library'. Its dependency 
 'kotlin' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin' is loaded prior to 
 'sample-library'.");
}`

so it's clear that the it's meant to be run with a file that instantiates `kotlin`.  Any ideas why I'm not seeing it?  I'm following the tutorial exactly as written.  I'm using the latest version of the compiler from homebrew, which is 1.1.2.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/kotlin-to-javascript/kotlin-to-javascript.html), yes, you'll need to include `kotlin.js` before you can run your own Kotlin code. This file contains the Kotlin runtime and standard library.

If you're doing this from the command line, you can find `kotlin.js` in the `lib` folder of the compiler, inside `kotlin-stdlib-js.jar` (which you can just open as a regular `.zip` file).

Comment: Aha! there it is. Thank you so much.  Note to other Node.js folks, you'll have to add `kotlin = require('./kotlin.js')` somewhere before your compiled JS runs.

Comment: ^ or better yet, compile with `-module-kind commonjs` after installing the kotlin dependency from npm.

Comment: @guyIntrepid that solved my issue! I'm building with IntelliJ, any reason you can think of why it wouldn't automatically add that in as a part of the build? :/

Comment: @guyIntrepid. This should be the correct answer. Someone beginning in the language should not have to decompress the runtime jars to get at the kotlin.js file, IMHO.

Comment: But yes, thumbs up tp @zsmb13, too. This is not obvious from the CLI tutorial.